# Вывести весь рядок из функции

Tags: sql, access

Здравсвтуйте, делаю лабораторную и столкнулся с такой задачей:

> Выявление этапов маршрутов с максимальной длинной, маршрут с
>   наибольшим числом туристов, что прошли по нему

Написал, данный код, выдает лишь 1 параметр нужного рядка, а нужно вывести полный ряд.

```
SELECT Max(Етап.Довжина) AS Выражение1
FROM (Маршрут INNER JOIN Етап ON Маршрут.id = Етап.Маршрут) INNER JOIN Подоріж ON Маршрут.id = Подоріж.Маршрут
WHERE (((Етап.Маршрут) In (SELECT t.Маршрут 
                      FROM Подоріж t
                      GROUP BY t.Маршрут
                      HAVING count(*)>1)));
```

Схема БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SELECT Max(Етап.Довжина) AS Выражение1, Етап.Тривалість, Етап.Довжина.....`

Comment: @Arendach Пишет: "**Ваш запрос не содержит выражение "Тривалість" как часть агрегатной функции**"